# Yanking line copies past kill-ring lines along with current

Tags: text-editing, copy-paste, kill-ring

I'm using Emacs to create text to copy to another program, but I need to copy line by line. I'm using a variation of `kill-ring-save` I provide below.

```
(defun my-kill-ring-save ()
    (interactive)
    (if (equal mark-active nil) (kill-ring-save (point) (line-end-position)) (kill-ring-save (point) (mark))))
(global-set-key "\M-w" 'my-kill-ring-save)
```

So I would do this:

1. `M-w` to copy the line
2. Alt-Tab to go to the other program
3. Ctrl-v to paste the line
4. Alt-Tab to go back to Emacs
5. `C-k` two times (delete the current line, and again so the next line moves up)
6. Repeat the process

The problem is that when I hit Ctrl-v in the other program sometimes it yanks not only the line I want, but other previously deleted lines. I read that the paste command should only paste the last line in the kill ring, thats what I would like it to do. This problem only happens (as far as I know) If I `C-k` two times fast and right after copying the line with M-w. If I kill lines with `C-k`, wait for 3 seconds, I'm able to `M-w` the current line and paste just this line. Sorry if it seems like a exageration of a small problem, but I'm actually doing this process a lot of times so any solution would be great for me. I couldn't find any related problem about this specficic issue.

EDIT: the solution below unfortunately didn't work or I couldn't use it correctly, appreciate any update on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill-ring-save` is for interactive use. To delete and store in `kill-ring`:

`(defun my-kill-ring-save-this-line ()
  (interactive "*")
  (kill-new (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))`

or if the properties are needed

`(defun my-kill-ring-save-prop-this-line ()
  (interactive "*")
  (kill-new (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))`

Delete a line but not store:

`(defun my-delete-line-this-line ()
  (interactive "*")
  (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))`

Comment: (defun kill-new ()
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-w") 'kill-new)

This gives me error command-execute: Wrong type of argument : commandp, kill-new

Comment: kill-new is provided by Emacs, installing it anew as defun would overwrite i.e. destroy the original. Write the interactive spec as you did in OP, than the body as provided in answer.

Comment: Edit the answer, all there meanwhile.

Comment: Still added the warnings if buffer is read-only.